# Getting the version of an ASDF system

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

Among other things you can set in an ASDF system is the `:version` property. Is there a way to read it at runtime? Something like `(system-version :my-system-name)`?

I know there are `asdf:version-satisfies`, and `asdf:asdf-version`, but neither do what I want in this case.

Comment: `(slot-value (asdf:find-system <system>) 'asdf:version)`

Comment: Using `slot-value` is abstraction-breaking, unlike the approach based on `component-version`, so the latter is better.  At least in theory, someone could write a method for `asdf:component-version` that does not access the slot, in which case code that directly examines the slot would lose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
(defun system-version (system-designator)
  (let ((system (asdf:find-system system-designator nil)))
    (when (and system (slot-boundp system 'asdf:version))
      (asdf:component-version system))))
```

it works like this:

```
CL-USER> (system-version :cffi)
"0.10.7.1"
CL-USER> (system-version :foo)
NIL
```